# using .parent() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through a few divs.

**Code:**

```
$(".tree  div ").each(function () {
    var _searchthis = $(this);
    var mySearchDiv = _searchthis.parent('div').attr('id');
    console.log("this is ID : " + $(this).attr('id'));
    console.log("this is parentID : " + mySearchDiv);
});
```

In case of ID, I am getting the value. But it does not return the `.parent('div').attr('id')`

I am getting "undefined".

Edited :

When I use `.closest()` ,instead of `.parent()`, I get the ID of `$(this)` only.
`.parents('div').first().attr('id')` also returns "undefined".

```
$(".tree li div ").each(function (){
....
}
```

was a desperate attempt.

HTML Code is more like: http://jsbin.com/yilaw/1/edit

===================================

## RESOLVED. I had problem with my HTML structure. Thanks Guys.

Comment: We need your html too

Comment: Isn't the `$(this)` not already the `div`? It looks like from your code that you don't have a `.parent('div')` but a `.parent('li')`.

Comment: Use closest('div') instead of parent('div')

Comment: `.tree li div` atrocious jQuery string

Comment: use `.closest()` to find the first parent to match a specific selector, and make sure that node actually _has_ an id

Comment: If `$(this)` is already a `div` you should use `parents('div')` because `.closest` also selects itself.

Comment: @putvande
Yes, $(this) is a Div. I do have a few Divs and Li's as Parents. Actually, each Div comes inside a Li.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your code to this:

```
_searchthis.parents("div").eq(0).attr('id');
```

Comment: Tried this. But I get "undefined".

I get all ID's for all Divs with ...$(this).attr('id').

But when it comes to ParentID, I get "undefined"

Comment: This works. I had problem with my HTML structure. Thanks guys for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

`.parent()` parent goes only to the first level  while `.parents()` goes up the stack.

Notice the difference here : http://jsbin.com/labugi/1/edit

#### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="firstLevel">
    <span id="secondLevel">
      <p id="thirdLevel">
        <i id="forthLevel">POC</i>
      </p>    
    <span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### javascript

```
var result = $('#forthLevel').parent('div').attr('id');
console.log('result of .parent("div"): '+ result);

var result = $('#forthLevel').parents('div').attr('id');
console.log('result of .parents("div"): '+ result);
```

JQuery says about parent : http://api.jquery.com/parent/

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Use `parents` instead and get the first element like so : `_searchthis.parents('div').eq(0);`

Please note : the search query that you are using might be very slow, use classes or ids if possible instead of tagNames.